# remove dropdown bottom line in flutter

Tags: flutter

How to remove  dropdown bottom line?

[image]

My Code

```
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 5, 10, 5),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  dropdownButton,
                  Expanded(child: phoneField),
                ],
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
            )
```

And this is Dropdown

```
 var dropdownButton = DropdownButton(
      value: dropdownValue,
      onChanged: (String newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newValue;
        });
      },
      items: <String>['99451', '99450', '99455', '99470 ']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to wrap your DropdownButton inside 
[DropdownButtonHideUnderline](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButtonHideUnderline-class.html) like this

```
var dropdownButton = DropdownButtonHideUnderline( 
  child: DropdownButton(
  value: dropdownValue,
  onChanged: (String newValue) { 
    setState(() { 
      dropdownValue = newValue; 
    });
 }, 
  items: <String>['99451', '99450', '99455', '99470 '].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>
    ((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>( 
            value: value, 
            child: Text(value), 
      ); 
      }).toList(), 
    )
 );
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use like that

```
underline: SizedBox()
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using

```
underline: Container(),
```

Full Changed Code

```
var dropdownButton = DropdownButton(
  value: dropdownValue,
  underline: Container(),
  onChanged: (String newValue) {
    setState(() {
      dropdownValue = newValue;
    });
  },
  items: <String>['99451', '99450', '99455', '99470 ']
      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: value,
      child: Text(value),

    );
  }).toList(),
);
```